# Capture video without audio in camerax

Tags: android, kotlin, audio, video, android-camerax

I want to capture video without audio in in-app camera using camerax api

I am using camerax api of beta10

I have tried by setting audio buffer size and audio sources etc.

Comment: by 'in-app' camera do you mean the built in camera app???

Answer (score 2):

At the time of this answer is not supported yet, but it will be possible when video recording using the camerax library is fully released.

The best approach is to wait for the official support release, as any workaround you find would be just hacks that may or not work in different devices, and that eventually will become obsolete.

See the google's recent answer:

https://groups.google.com/a/android.com/g/camerax-developers/c/fsY3j4x_lA0/m/921lFEqyAgAJ

As a temporary alternative, **meanwhile video isn't fully supported by the CameraX API**, you could code it by directly using the camera2 API. As you can see in the [official sample](https://github.com/android/camera-samples/tree/main/Camera2Video), is actually quite simple and doesn't require too much coding.

If you are concerned about the difference between the CameraX and Camera2 APIs, note that CameraX is a wrapper around the Camera2 API, so no need to worry.